# Looking for lat/long coordinates of proposed Northern Gateway pipeline route

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for a list of lat/long coordinates of the proposed Northern Gateway pipeline route, which Enbridge (an oil company) wants to build in BC. My goal is to build a web app that displays the proposed pipeline route on a map, along with other information.

Does anyone know where I could find that data?

Comment: I did a little sniffing and thought I'd found something (on gatewayfacts.ca) relevant for you; then I saw that you'd posted the question! I see they didn't actually give it to you as data; anyway, might be worth adding as a note in your question that you've pursued that. People may have tips on how to convert the map they gave you to GIS data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Pipe Up Against Enbridge has the data your after, i.e., http://pipeupagainstenbridge.ca/the-project/map

My colleague @HughStimson is contacting them about the data in the hopes that we can get permission to host as part of the GeoDataBC collection (https://github.com/geodatabc). (PS We're looking for contributors!)

In the meantime, it appears that the necessary data is linked from that map, e.g.:

http://pipeupagainstenbridge.ca/images/map/pipelineroute.kml

You'll probably want to check-in with them about the license / source for the data.

Good luck!

Phillip.

Comment: Thanks Phillip! And I'll make sure to keep GeoDataBC in mind.

Comment: NG pipeline route data as geoJSON can be found at https://github.com/geodatabc/NorthernGatewayPipeline.

Comment: ...which means it's already viewable on an open data (OpenStreetMap) basemap: https://github.com/geodatabc/NorthernGatewayPipeline/blob/master/pipelineroute.geojson    (gotta love that github feature)